# Alternating signs of significant estimates in VAR model

Tags: r, interpretation, vector-autoregression

I have 6 variables and 125 observations, which I am modelling using a VAR model, in which I put all variables in as edogenous, as all relationships interest me (the bidirectionality). I have carried out granger tests, detrended my data (i.e., checked the stationarity, taken logs, log_difference as necessary) so all variables come into the model stationary.

For the lag I set `lag.max = 6`, and use the AIC criterion in the model (which never returns a lag larger than 5 anyway).

The model works fine and I can read the answers off, with significance here and there, more or less confirming my hypotheses that I made before the test.

I am looking at how the inventories of oil are related to another factor (Net Convenience Yield, WTI Oil) This relationship gets 2 lags from AIC. Then my results:

```
summary(equations="NCY_WTI_3M",VAR(data.final[,c("NCY_WTI_3M","NCY_BRE_3M","SP","INV")],
type="const", ic="AIC", lag.max=LagMax))

    VAR Estimation Results:
    ========================= 
    Endogenous variables: NCY_WTI_3M, NCY_BRE_3M, SP, INV 
    Deterministic variables: const 
    Sample size: 123 
    Log Likelihood: -763.052 
    Roots of the characteristic polynomial:
    0.8509 0.8509 0.5029 0.5029 0.4318 0.4318 0.2642 0.2151
    Call:
    VAR(y = data.final[, c("NCY_WTI_3M", "NCY_BRE_3M", "SP", "INV")], 
        type = "const", lag.max = LagMax, ic = "AIC")


    Estimation results for equation NCY_WTI_3M: 
    =========================================== 
    NCY_WTI_3M = NCY_WTI_3M.l1 + NCY_BRE_3M.l1 + SP.l1 + INV.l1 + NCY_WTI_3M.l2 + NCY_BRE_3M.l2 + SP.l2 + INV.l2 + const 

                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    NCY_WTI_3M.l1  5.018e-01  9.903e-02   5.067 1.57e-06 ***
    NCY_BRE_3M.l1  5.096e-01  1.213e-01   4.201 5.30e-05 ***
    SP.l1          1.230e-01  2.182e-01   0.564  0.57393    
    INV.l1        -2.578e-06  8.847e-07  -2.914  0.00429 ** 
    NCY_WTI_3M.l2 -1.889e-01  8.721e-02  -2.166  0.03237 *  
    NCY_BRE_3M.l2  1.613e-01  1.435e-01   1.124  0.26351    
    SP.l2          5.887e-01  2.205e-01   2.669  0.00871 ** 
    INV.l2         1.889e-06  8.528e-07   2.215  0.02875 *  
    const          1.984e-01  1.012e-01   1.961  0.05234 .  
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The problem is that both `INV.l1` and `INV.l2` have significance in this model, however they have differing effects. `INV.l1` (**) has a negative estimate, whereas `INV.l2` (*) has a positive estimate - this means a differing relationship over time periods, if both being significant should be believed.

This 'anomaly' has appeared in practically every model I have run from all 27 variables (using smaller basket models), where each time a factor has significance, the estimates provided have different signs (+/-).

**I don't believe this is the case, and so my question is, is there an inherent property of VAR models that might help to explain this?**

I was thinking, if the effect from `lag1` on today is positive, then the effect from `lag2` on `lag1` should also be positive, so what is the expected effect from `lag2` on today? Does the fact that the sign changes with each lag, mean that there is actually some consistency over the whole time series?

UPDATE: After speaking to other people, my current theory is that there is an ilk of overcorrection occurring. The second lagged variable has an effect on the independent variable only after the first lagged variable has been taken into account. In this train of thought, my 'problem' would then be created by a kind of mean-reversion effect, whereby the calculation always partially overshoots the mark and thus producing the positive / negative signs in front of my estimated values.

Comment: Comment from SO before deletions:
 I don't see why you don't want to accept that the influence of L(x) can change through time. You can think of it as a correction on the correction and there are plenty of time series with different signs on the L1 vs L2 that are stationary. I would suggest scaling your data first such that all right hand side inputs are on a similar scale so you don't get caught out by distribution differences between your inputs. Hans Roggeman

Comment: Thanks, @Dexter. this may be a better venue for your question. It strikes me as more about the nature of the model than about the code to produce it. Hopefully you'll get a good answer soon.

Comment: Usually in VAR modelling the effect of one variable to another is measured using impulse response functions. Do not forget that your model is endogenous so depending on the relationships with other variables the differing signs in two different periods do not necessarily means that there is differing relationships in those periods.

Comment: @mpiktas - that's good new to receive!  Impuslse Response Tests are something I would like to go on to do in order to make prognoses, have I understood correctly that it could then also explain the 'alternating' relationship in my output above? Could you give me any further advice about this interpetation, or where I could read more about it? Is there a term I could search for in books/academic papers? Thanks again!

Comment: The academic term is the same, impulse response function. Any textbook on VAR, should have a chapter on IRF.